# Is $\log(z-\alpha)$ well defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Could you help me with the following problem please:

Show that if $U\subset{\mathbb{C}}$ is simply connected domain and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}\setminus U$, then log$(z-\alpha)$ is well defined for all $z\in U$

I have no idea how to solve this problem, it arose at the time of proving the Riemann mapping theorem, but it does not occur to me how to do the proof, also, I have tried to see it taking the case in which U is an open ball, but not I can understand well what the exercise says, since if, for example, I took the unit ball centered on the origin, there would still be values in which the logarithm would not be well defined. I hope you can help me with this, thank you.

**My try:**

We fix a point $z_0\in U$ and let's define:
$$
\log(z-\alpha)=\displaystyle\int_{\gamma(z)}\dfrac{1}{w-\alpha}dw+\log(z_0-\alpha)
$$
with $\gamma(z)$ a path in $U$ that joins $z$ with $z_0$.

And it would be necessary to see that in this case the integral does not depend on the path, I think that would suffice, but I have not managed to prove it, it occurs to me that it is because it is a simply connected domain and applying Cauchy's theorem

Comment: Hint: Show that $\frac{1}{z-\alpha}$ has an antiderivative on $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I'd proceed by doing a further step remembering the following facts:

1. [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem): if $f: U\to \Bbb C$ is a holomorphic function on the domain $U$, then
   $$
   \oint\limits_\gamma f(w)\mathrm{d}w=0
   $$
   for each simple closed curve contained in $U$.
2. If $\alpha \in \Bbb C\setminus U$ then
   $$
   f(w)=\frac{1}{w-\alpha}\quad \forall w\in U
   $$
   is holomorphic on the whole $U$. To see this note that, by putting $w\equiv x+iy$, we have
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{x+iy-\alpha} \\
   & = -\frac{1}{(x+iy-\alpha)^2}\\
   & = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{1}{x+iy-\alpha}= -i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)
   \end{split}
   $$
   thus $f$ satisfies the [*Cauchy-Riemann* equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Conformal_mappings) on the whole $U$ since it is continuous with its partial derivatives for any $w\in U$ due to the hypothesis $\alpha \in \Bbb C\setminus U$.

Now the definition of $\log(z-\alpha)$ as given above is seen to be path independent since, for any two continuous paths $\gamma_1[z],\gamma_2[z]: [0,1]\to U$ joining $z_0$ to $z$ in $U$
$$
\oint\limits_{\gamma_1[z]}\frac{1}{w-\alpha}\mathrm{d}w = \oint\limits_{\gamma_2[z]}\frac{1}{w-\alpha}\mathrm{d}w \iff \oint\limits_{\gamma_1\cup [-\gamma_2]}\frac{1}{w-\alpha}\mathrm{d}w=0
$$
provided having defined the closed curve $\gamma_1\cup [-\gamma_2]:[0,1]\to \Bbb C$ as
$$
\gamma_1\cup [-\gamma_2](t)=
\begin{cases}
\gamma_1[z](2t) & t\in \big[0,\frac{1}{2}\big[\\
\gamma_2[z](2- 2t) & t\in \big[\frac{1}{2},1\big]
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $\log(z-\alpha)$ is univocally defined.

**Final notes**

- As @Haus said in the comments, the choice of $z_0\in U$ is exactly the choice of the branch of the logarithm we are willing to use: once you chose $z_0$, the additive constant becomes $\log(z_0-\alpha)$ and is fully determined for the whole simply connected domain $U$. If we consider $\alpha=0$ and $U=\Bbb C\setminus {0}$ (which is not simply connected) we see that it is not so: depending on how we encircle $0$ by the path $\gamma[z]$ (clockwise or counterclockwise, starting from an arbitrary $z_0\neq 0$), we have that
  $$
  \log z =\log |z| + i\arg z 
  $$
  where the imaginary part is only known modulo $2n\pi i$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and thus not uniquely determined.
- The curve $\gamma_1\cup[-\gamma_2]$ has been defined in perhaps a cumbersome way in order to show how it is closed. Intuitively speaking, when the parameter $t$ rises from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, the mapped point "moves" along $\gamma_1$ from $z_0$ to the (chosen and fixed) $z$: when it further rises beyond $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$, the mapped point "moves" from $z$ to $z_0$ "reversing its motion". This later behavior is the reason for the highly nonstandard and perhaps unfortunate notation $[-\gamma_2]$ I've chosen for this part of the composite path: I wanted to find something that would remind the reader of the addition of simplexes in euclidean spaces, in order to make the concept intuitively clear, but I've obviously failed.
- Strictly speaking, the reasoning above requires the two paths $\gamma_1[z]$ and $\gamma_2[z]$ to be non intersecting: however, the integral calculated on them can be seen to be equal to the one calculated on an auxiliary path joining $z$ to $z_0$ *and not interesting any of them*, thus the independence of the definition of the complex logarithm holds without any restriction on the used path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have the following questions:
1.- In the definition of log$(z-\alpha)$ as the integral, would it be necessary to add the term log$(z_0-\alpha)$ to choose a specific branch of the logarithm?

2.-In the solution, when you define the closed curve $\gamma_1 \cup [- \gamma_2]$, what does $[- \gamma_2]$ represent? (I think it is only to avoid making mistakes in notation, but I would like to confirm it) and why is this curve necessarily closed?

Comment: I have already seen why it is closed is how you define it, excuse me.

Comment: @Haus I'll add some notes in order to clarify the points you have inquired about. And do not worry if you have realized after posting the comment that the curve $\gamma_1\cup[-\gamma_2]$ is closed: as I usually say, there are no trivial questions, just questions, and a Q&A website like Math.SE is fueled by them.

Comment: Thank you very much, very kind, I have a problem with that part that I mentioned adding that adding or I do not know if it would be necessary to specify in which branch we are taking the values, I do not know, this exercise has me somewhat confused, but I repeat, thank you very much, your answer So far it has cleared up many doubts for me.

Comment: Everything clear now, no doubt, really thank you very much.